# SharePoint 2019: SSA topology Index Partition shows State Degraded when Windows Service SearchHostController is running as the "services" account

Tags: searchserviceapplication, 2019, index-component

- This is a test SharePoint 2019 MinRole farm with 2 servers (1 App with Search, 2 Front-End with Distributed Cache).
- In Central Administration I see the yellow warning under Index Partition 0 since it was set up.
- When running `Get-SPEnterpriseSearchStatus -SearchApplication $ssa |ft -Autosize Name, State, Details` IndexComponent State shows Degraded.
- If I change the Windows Service SearchHostController Service Account in Central Admin from the "services" account to the "farm" account, this issue will get fixed.
- I have checked all permissions to make sure they are correct.

Any idea about how to resolve this issue with the account used to run SearchHostController?

Comment: Services account need to have policy rights: "Run as Service", has it ? You can try to add this account to Server Administrators, if it works too, if yes, there will be only some rights problem. Try it please

Comment: @ZdeněkVinduška Added "services" account to the Server Administrators and State changed from Degraded to Active. As I can not leave this account in the admin group, I need to find out what permission it is missing so it can work properly for the IndexComponent as for the other components. Any ideas?Thank you very much.

Comment: policy right - Run As Service - for windows service of search, add this account as Admininstartor - Go to CA > Service Applications > Select Search Service Application > in ribbon Permission > add account with full control

Comment: 1- "services" account already had "Log on as a service" in the server's Local Security Policy.
2- Added "services" with Full Control under Permissions in Search Service Application 
3- removed the account from the Server's administrator group in Active Directory.

Comment: I added answer, you can mark it as correct :) your will be probably deleted cause it "thank youL answer

Comment: I started having this issue again. Permissions are the same as when the issue got resolved.

Comment: Have you tried restart servers? The index should be fixed automatically, but it takes some tome depends on the size of the Index.

Comment: IndexComponent State gets fixed immediately when running SearchHostController as the "farm" account, but it has to run as "services". The Index RootDirectory is set up on D:\SearchIndex\0 instead of C drive. Could that be the issue with "services" account? that it can not properly access the D drive location?

Comment: Check permissions on folders, make sure this account is in WPG_Admin_WSS group on server

Comment: "services" account is already a member of WSS_ADMIN_WPG group on server. Any other idea about where else to check?

Comment: restarting the server didn't fix the issue neither

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning Modify permissions for the "services" account at the folder level on the server on D:\SearchIndex (where the index partition is located) fixed the Degraded State.

Answer (score 2):

1. policy right - Run As Service - for windows service of search
2. add this account as Admininstartor - Go to CA > Service Applications > Select Search Service Application > in ribbon Permission > add account with full control

*Hope it helps!*